# How can I stop MS word from pushing text to different pages with manual breaks?

Tags: microsoft-word

I'm in MS word creating a script for a voice actor, and I can't figure out how someone would set up pages so that, no matter how many times they add manual breaks, text from one page wouldn't be pushed to another or dragged up to another page. Every time you add a manual break or simply type a new line, it pushes down all text below it onto another page, and every time you delete a line, it moves up all text below it to a preceding page. How can this be stopped for each individual page, so that individual sentences on a page can be moved up and down, but the content on different pages doesn't interfere with each other?

Some sources say to check or uncheck the "Window/Orphan" control in the paragraph settings. This literally does nothing either way, text still spills over into pages exactly as it did before.

Comment: There is no general solution.

Comment: There are already two solutions that work for some people. They just happen to not work for me, and I can't seem to find another option, or there is some other hidden setting I may have altered that is preventing the first two from functioning.

Comment: The behaviour you describe ("every time you delete a line, it moves up all text below it to a preceding page") seems fundamental to how Word operates. Perhaps it is not the right tool for this task (voice actor scripts).

Comment: If you want to post this on softwarerecs you should drop Word as a requirement. Maybe there is a better tool for this. If the tool exists, you could probably export the final result to Word so that others can view it. If you insist on Word there *might* be a VBA solution but you would have to program that yourself to simulate the behaviour you want.